# unistall hydro version

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I have three different versions of ROS installed on my system and i want to unistall Hydro. I can not do it with

> sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro

I think it is a wrong command. Does anyone know how should i do it??? thanks:))

---

I could unistall it successfully and I tried to reinstall hydro because it had some problems. When i try again i see:

> The following packages have unmet
> dependencies:  ros-hydro-desktop-full
> : Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it
> is not going to be installed E: Unable
> to correct problems, you have held
> broken packages.

Does anyone know what is the problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193698/unistall-hydro-version/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how about

> sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro-*

---

Originally posted by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) with karma: 148 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-09-29**:
it works. thanks:))

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-30**:
@mohammad please accept the answer using the checkmark at left so others know your problem is solved.